# Want to run and connect to a lightweight FTP server on my own machine

Tags: ftp, sftp

I'm writing a bash script which automates the downloading of files from an FTP server depending on certain conditions.

For testing I need to be able to connect to an FTP server, list the files there, upload and download the files. I tried searching for public FTP servers which would let me connect to them using **sftp** command but to no avail.

Is there a lightweight FTP server that I can install on my own computer, and connect to it through the command line as if it were a real world scenario?

Kindly keep in mind before answering that I haven't installed any FTP server before, so I would really appreciate a detailed answer.

Thank you!

Comment: FTP or SFTP? They're completely different protocols. SFTP was called this way because its commands are similar to FTP, but it isn't an additional layer to FTP or anything close like this, not like HTTPS with HTTP.

Comment: @Gilles I need SFTP protocol to connect to the FTP server.

Comment: You can't use the SFTP protocol to connect to an FTP server. They're different protocols. Some FTP servers support FTPS, but that's a different protocols. Many but not all clients support both.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on using `sftp`, you need install `sshd` (the [ssh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) server demon), because `sftp` works over the ssh-protocol and is not really an ftp program in the original sense. It's just a more ftp-like interface that works similarly to `scp` etc.

If you want to use real ftp, the "classic" client is usually called `ftp` and the "classic" server is called `ftpd`. Try these first, if you are not content, play around with the alternatives like `vsftp` (more lightweight, but with security restrictions you have to pay attention).

If you are looking at the alternatives, keep in mind that TFTP as used by `tftp` is again a different protocol (*trivial* file transfer program, simplified compared to FTP).